# Android: imageView padding

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I'm trying to add a picture via imageView. But I want to full fill my view with the image and also the imageView should fill the width of the screen. the image should begin and end at the screen edge's.

I used every xml attributes but no luck. This is the closest code to what I want.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bck3"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonStore"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/store" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ronaldo" />
```

[image: Screenshot]

**It should be this**
[image: What it should look like]

Comment: What is your container layout?  Are there any margins or padding set there?  We need to see more of your XML to help.

Comment: Please feel free to post your xml code fully. So that we can help you with it.

Comment: I added the full xml code.  note: I deleted the action bar in Manifest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try removing the following code from relative layout properties:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Remove the padding on the parent layout, your imageview will then fill the entire width